# Is there a way to make react-select have collapsible groups?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I am working with react-select, and a variant of it, react-multiselect-checkboxes. I would like to make the group sections collapsible, but have been unable to figure out how.

I have made a custom group header component that has a down caret added to it. But, I can't figure out the best way to add an "active" class to a particular group when this item is clicked. I was planning on just using CSS to show/hide the group divs based on what was active.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9o8o1n90mr

I would expect that when the caret is clicked, the proper items under the group would show/hide accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A bit hacky around mutating state but something along these lines? https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sara-9wssn

Basically providing Group rather than GroupHeading and showing/hiding children based on the expanded state

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom `GroupHeader` and register a click event and write a login in click handler to hide and show the options under a group

Check below sandbox. I have created a sample example over there.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gp4i4

so basically you will write below code to create custom `GroupHeader` component and,
logic to hide and show options under a group on click event.

```
// handle options group header click event
// hide and show the options under clicked group
const handleHeaderClick = id => {
  const node = document.querySelector(`#${id}`).parentElement
    .nextElementSibling;
  const classes = node.classList;
  if (classes.contains("collapsed")) {
    node.classList.remove("collapsed");
  } else {
    node.classList.add("collapsed");
  }
};

// Create custom GroupHeading component, which will wrap
// react-select GroupHeading component inside a div and
// register onClick event on that div
const CustomGroupHeading = props => {
  return (
    <div
      className="group-heading-wrapper"
      onClick={() => handleHeaderClick(props.id)}
    >
      <components.GroupHeading {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

It is not the optimal solution, but it works.

I have also written a blog about it, have a look

https://www.chintanradia.com/blog/react-select-collapsible-group/#collapsible-grouped-options

Comment: That's neat.
I wonder how would you handle state in case you want to have a caret/chevron icon indicating  if the group is collapsed or not. Thoughts?